# How to wrap hardcoded array in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to separate some part of my arrays so I can make the details dynamic and different in my WordPress website.

I'm using [ACF](http://advancedcustomfields.com/) to get my custom post type taxonomy and trying to generate some attributes and make them tabs using the **acf_add_local_field_group** function but unfortunately am not able to make it work.

The reason why I want to separate the array is because am not able to call `global $post;` and I have a function which is a meta box for that to retrieve the taxonomy terms.

Here is my code:

```
function my_acf_add_local_field_groups()
{
    acf_add_local_field_group(array(
        'key' => 'tab_group_1',
        'title' => 'Product Sizes and Prices',
        'name' => 'group_sizes_tab',
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'field_tab_size_1',
                'label' => 'First Size',
                'name' => 'store_sizes_',
                'type' => 'tab',
                'parent' => 'tab_group_1',
                'instructions' => '',
                'required' => 0,
                'conditional_logic' => 0,
                'wrapper' => array(
                    'width' => '',
                    'class' => '',
                    'id' => '',
                ) ,
                'collapsed' => '',
                'min' => '',
                'max' => '',
            ) ,
            array(
                'key' => 'field_unique_key',
                'label' => 'Simple Repeater',
                'name' => 'simple_repeater',
                'type' => 'repeater',
                'instructions' => '',
                'required' => 0,
                'conditional_logic' => 0,
                'wrapper' => array(
                    'width' => '',
                    'class' => '',
                    'id' => '',
                ) ,
                'collapsed' => '',
                'min' => 0,
                'max' => 10,
                'layout' => 'table',
                'button_label' => 'Add row',
                'sub_fields' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'field_unique_key_1',
                        'label' => 'Total Products',
                        'name' => 'total_products',
                        'type' => 'text',
                    ) ,
                    array(
                        'key' => 'field_unique_key_2',
                        'label' => 'Total Prices',
                        'name' => 'total_prices',
                        'type' => 'text',
                    ) ,
                ) ,
            ) ,
            array(
                'key' => 'field_tab_size_2',
                'label' => 'Second Size',
                'name' => 'store_sizes_2',
                'type' => 'tab',
                'parent' => 'tab_group_1',
                'instructions' => '',
                'required' => 0,
                'conditional_logic' => 0,
                'wrapper' => array(
                    'width' => '',
                    'class' => '',
                    'id' => '',
                ) ,
                'collapsed' => '',
                'min' => '',
                'max' => '',
            ) ,
        ) ,
        'location' => array(
            array(
                array(
                    'param' => 'post_type',
                    'operator' => '==',
                    'value' => 'products',
                ) ,
            ) ,
        ) ,
    ));
}
add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_add_local_field_groups');
```

As you can see in the `group_sizes_tab` the `fields` value is the one I want to separate. Am thinking storing it in a variable but when I tested it it doesn't work.

Just to make it short, basically outside the function it'll be like this:

```
$fields = array(
    'key' => 'field_tab_size_1',
    'label' => 'First Size',
    'name' => 'store_sizes_',
    'type' => 'tab',
    'parent' => 'tab_group_1',
    'instructions' => '',
    'required' => 0,
    'conditional_logic' => 0,
    'wrapper' => array(
        'width' => '',
        'class' => '',
        'id' => '',
    ) ,
    'collapsed' => '',
    'min' => '',
    'max' => '',
);
```

Then I replace this value inside the function but it is not working.

How can I wrap the array and replace it with a variable in the function?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking

Comment: How can I wrap the array and replace it with a variable in the function

Comment: Do you mean you pass `$fields` in as a parameter to your function (`function my_acf_add_local_field_groups($fields)`) and then want to do `'fields' => $fields,` in the array inside the function?

Comment: @NigelRen exactly

Comment: Having read up on `add_action`, I'm not sure if you can pass parameters into the function at this point as the function is called at some other point in the code.